# can I have two rows that have same contents except 1 column

Tags: mysql

I made a database and store information of pass, etc. Now I am in step in updating a pass. I edit 1 column of table of pass. Can I do like this ? or is it wrong ? [image: pass table]

Comment: Why would it be wrong? :)

Comment: so when I select serial of pass, I need to select only the last updated pass ? how can I do so if I want the second one ?

Comment: So your question is how you can differentiate two records which have the same serialNo?

Comment: I just want to know more by this question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First obtain the max(updateTag) from the table and then execute the following query

```
Select serialNo from table where updateTag = <Max update flag obtained in previous query>
```

Comment: Thank you ! it works ! If I have many passes , then I get many updateTag, how can I select them all ?

Comment: Can you be more specific on your question

Comment: I mean that this pass table can have many passes, so each pass can have different updateTag. Then, how can I select max of those updateTag ?

Comment: add another condition in the where clause for the passTypeID

Comment: if I use same passTypeID , so ... ?

Comment: Give a sample data and sample output so that can give a clear result